# How would I obtain a list of values using SQL to connect to an XML API?

Tags: sql, xml, vba, excel

We have a cloud donor database we use at my nonprofit but it has an XML API that can allow us to interact with the database outside of the GUI. The use cases in the documentation presented are all about integrating the database with our website, but I want to use it to automate repetitive, time-consuming reports.

I figured out that I can throw a SQL statement into the connection URL to pull the numbers we need, but I have to connect and retrieve information for every single cell in the report, pulling one sum at a time, so it takes a while. I am using a macro-enabled spreadsheet and VBA to run a bunch of these API calls and inserting the results into cells. Is there a way to retrieve an XML document that would contain ALL of the values, and I could just iterate over that? I am thinking it is all of the API calls and wait times that is slowing this down.

This is an example connection string with the login and pass omitted:

```
https://www.donorperfect.net/prod/xmlrequest.asp?login=*****&pass=*****&action= SELECT SUM(dpgift.amount) from dpgift INNER JOIN dpgiftudf ON dpgift.gift_id=dpgiftudf.gift_id WHERE dpgiftudf.bu2_category = '01WEB' AND dpgift.record_type = 'G' AND dpgift.gift_date BETWEEN '3/1/2017' AND '3/31/2017'
```

Just the SQL in the URL is:

```
SELECT SUM(dpgift.amount) 
from dpgift 
INNER JOIN dpgiftudf ON dpgift.gift_id=dpgiftudf.gift_id 
WHERE dpgiftudf.bu2_category = '01WEB' 
AND dpgift.record_type = 'G' 
AND dpgift.gift_date BETWEEN '3/1/2017' AND '3/31/2017'
```

The result of this is the following:

```
<result><record><field name="" id="" value="2995"/></record></result>
```

I have to do this for every cell in the report, and there are about 500 cells.

I would like to pull it so the resulting XML would give me all of the values in the date range for ALL of the `bu2_category` codes, without doing a separate call for each individual value (e.g. one fancy SQL query that gives me one single XML document with all the fields and values during that time period).

Can anyone suggest a better SQL statement that I could try? I am new to SQL and XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider removing the `WHERE` condition on *bu2_category* and add a `GROUP BY` clause by the category. This will then sum *amount* for each distinct category.

```sql
SELECT dpgift.bu2_category, SUM(dpgift.amount) AS SumAmount
FROM dpgift 
INNER JOIN dpgiftudf ON dpgift.gift_id=dpgiftudf.gift_id 
WHERE dpgift.record_type = 'G' 
AND dpgift.gift_date BETWEEN '3/1/2017' AND '3/31/2017'
GROUP BY dpgift.bu2_category
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It gave me exactly what I needed. I now retrieved all the data in a second. Now I have to throw away all that code I wrote yesterday, and figure out how to actually parse the XML. I am sure once I get it working it will be lightning fast, since it obtained every sum in less than a second (previously you could see my program filling in each cell at the rate of one cell a second). This is exciting.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help! If solution helped please accept (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.